# Twilio Receiving multiple incoming calls from Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-voice

I am battling to get this working. My scenario, we are two developers trying to create a Twilio POC due tomorrow for our company. We are left with one scenario which does not seem to be working well. We have published our POC on Azure and setup the webhooks in Twilio Account Management Page for Incoming and Outbound.

We are calling one of our 'numbers', i.e. the same number, however, when connection.accept() is hit, we both answer and there is no way to choose which number to answer. We need to display this list of incoming calls, so that a agent can choose which to pick up. We used the example based on 'browser-calls-master' for a support_agent and customer.

I would think this is simple enough for Twilio, but not sure where we are wrong. Can the sample as it is work for multiple agents? When multiple calls come in, agent one should pick the first and if agent two click accept too, on their desktop client, they should pick the next call.

We also had a look at the Task Router, but it is too confusing and do not have ample time to incorporate it in our solution. Our solution is way simple, multiple calls, calling one team, and an available agent being able to accept.

If this fails tomorrow, my company is outsourcing to a different solution, please help? Sample code or documentation would help.

Comment: Hey Donny, I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio. Would love to try to help here, but it would likely be best to chat outside of StackOverflow for this. Can you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com and we'll see if we can sort this out for you.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?